# When plotting a 2D graph, should I draw the arrowheads on the axes?

Tags: soft-question, graphing-functions

When plotting a 2D function on $x-y$ plane, should I draw the arrowheads on the axes (Fig. A) or not (Fig. B)?
[image]

Are both ways considered *correct*?

Is there any occasion in which one is preferred than the other?

Or it is just a matter of style (and that we only need to be consistent with our choice)?

Comment: It is entirely a matter of choice.  I usually don't even label my axes, but that's me.

Comment: I prefer putting arrow, as it then indicates the direction/order

Comment: It's up to you but I'd go with the arrows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrows are superfluous, are not needed, and in fact [some of the best calculus books on the market](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html) don't use them at all.

Comment: Are arrows superfluous because the locations of axis labels already imply the ascending directions of those axes?

Comment: @PetchPuttichai, the x-axis is *always* oriented to the right and the $-y$-axis always oriented to the top according to the standard convention in the plane.  In 3-d the labels $x,y,z$ already indicate the positive direction, as you point out.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Arrows are useful in physics and engineering, where often you have to first choose a reference frame adapted to the problem considered. E.g. for a mass falling by gravity, you could choose your y axis pointing downwards. Your initial velocity along y can be positive or negative: the sign here is relative to the choice of direction of the axis. If you solve a problem with a certain direction of axes and you find a solution with a negative component, then you know it goes the opposite direction as the arrow drawn.

Axes are a spatial extension of basis vectors. A vector is a "mathematical arrow" - direction is an important property. E.g. in 3D, showing arrows on axes is important to know whether you have [right-handed coordinates or left-handed coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule). This distinction is important when looking at transformations of space (sign of determinant of matrices).

It makes no sense at all to have arrows at both ends, I don't quite understand how this suddenly appeared in schools in some countries. It's a bad habit to get rid of.

No arrows is fine but only if you add tics (numbers), that show the direction of increasing numbers. Otherwise the graph can be ambiguous. E.g. often kymographs show the time going downwards.

Scientific plots use a frame rather than axes, because it makes it easier to measure coordinates accurately e.g. using a ruler. The frame would always have tic labels (at least 3) on all sides, so the directions of increasing values is clear, as well as the scale (linear, logarithmic).